# How to alter file type and then save to a new directory?

Tags: python, directory, biopython

I have been attempting to change all files in a folder of a certain type to another and then save them to another folder I have created.

In my example the files are being changed from '.dna' files to '.fasta' files. I have successfully completed this via this code:

```
files = Path(directory).glob('*.dna')
for file in files:
          record = snapgene_file_to_seqrecord(file)
          fasta = record.format("fasta")
          print(fasta)
```

My issue is now with saving these files to a new folder. My attempt has been to use this:

```
save_path = Path('/Users/user/Documents...')
for file in files:
    with open(file,'w') as a:
          record = snapgene_file_to_seqrecord(a)
          fasta = record.format("fasta").read()
          with open(save_path, file).open('w') as f:
              f.write(fasta)
```

No errors come up but it is definitely not working. I can see that there may be an issue with how I am writing this but I can't currently think of a better way to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, You can use *os* lib to rename the file with the new extension (type)**

```
import os
my_file = 'my_file.txt'
base = os.path.splitext(my_file)[0]
os.rename(my_file, base + '.bin')
```

**And you can use *shutil* lib to move the file to a new directory.**

```
import shutil

# absolute path
src_path = r"E:\pynative\reports\sales.txt"
dst_path = r"E:\pynative\account\sales.txt"
shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)
```

Hope that can be of help.